# Display Popup on page load using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, visibility

The following is my HTML for popup:

```
<div id="overlay">

     <div>
        <header>
            <h2 class="modalHeader">Disclaimer:</h2>
        </header>
        <p>"xxxxxxxx"</p>           
        <button id="acceptButton" onclick="overlay()">Accept</button>

     </div>
</div>
```

The following is my CSS for the popup that is of concern:

```
#overlay {
     visibility:   hidden;
     /*position: absolute;*/
     left:         0px;
     top:          0px;
     width:        100%;
     height:       100%;
     text-align:   justify;
     z-index:      1000;
     font-family:  candara;
```

}

The following is my JavaScript to make popup  appear on pageload:

```
function popup{
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
overlay.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

I am trying to change the css `visibility: hidden` to `visibility:  visible`....why is this not working?

Comment: Your onclick="overlay()" function is calling overlay instead of popup? and your popup function need parentheses

Comment: Im new to web dev...I know my coding style isn't the greatest for this yet

Comment: I'm just pointing out the issues, you can try fix it and see whether the popup works.

Comment: @Syahrul the missing parentheses is what was the problem....do you recommend deleting the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the questions have flaws, if you make "overlay" hidden initially , then what will click ?
- on clicking the button "accept" you are calling a function which is not there .
- the function is defined and declared  always using parenthesis () , which is missing in your question .

Solution 
1: I  have given id to the p element as p1 in my demo , initially made it hidden by using visibility:   hidden;
2: on clicking the button calling appropriate function which is making the paragraph visible .

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/5aww1sef/2/

```
<script>
function overlay() {
    var overlay = document.getElementById("p1");
    overlay.style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>


<div id="overlay">
     <div>
        <header>
            <h2 class="modalHeader">Disclaimer:</h2>
        </header>
        <p  id="p1">"xxxxxxxx"</p>           
        <button id="acceptButton" onclick="overlay()">Accept</button>

     </div>
</div>

#overlay {
     left:         0px;
     top:          0px;
     width:        100%;
     height:       100%;
     text-align:   justify;
     z-index:      1000;
     font-family:  candara;
}
#p1{
     visibility:   hidden;
}
```

Comment: I have another function that was added.  The popup is a disclaimer.  When user accepts it disappears.  Thanks for you input.  I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Missing syntax here - with parentheses - also you'll need to call popup() as the function to call on click or when you need it.  I assume the button inside the overlay is to do another function like close the overlay right?

```
function popup() {
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
overlay.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use `display:none;` as  `visibility:hidden;` take up space on the page. Use the display property to create invisible elements that do not take up space

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/5sep0y5f/

**Code**

```
document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block'; // show

document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none'; // hide
```